# After restart run the batch file in Administartor mode

Tags: powershell, batch-file, restart, access-denied

I am trying to do the following:-

1. Run a script
2. Restart
3. Run Some Script block automatically
4. Restart
5. And so on.

I found out the following Code Snippet which helps me achieve it.

```
# Temp Folder
if (!(Get-Item d:\temp -ea ignore)) { mkdir d:\temp }

$dropperscript = 'C:\temp\dropper.ps1'

$dropper = @'
#############################################
###        Configuration Variables        ###
                                            #
# Put any variables you'll use here
                                            # 
###                                       ###
#############################################

# Static Variables
$countfile = 'd:\temp\bootcount.txt'
$bootbatch = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\dropper.bat'
$dropperscript = 'd:\temp\dropper.ps1'

#################
##### Setup #####

# Bootstrap Batch
if (!(Get-Item $bootbatch -ea ignore)) {
    "powershell -c $dropperscript`npause" | Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM'
}

# Boot Count
if (Get-Item $countfile -ea ignore) {
    [int]$bootcount = Get-Content $countfile
    if ($bootcount -match "^\d{1,2}$") { ([int]$bootcount) ++ }
    else { $bootcount = 1 }
}
else { $bootcount = 1 }
$bootcount | Out-File $countfile


switch ($bootcount) {

    1 {

       Get-Process | Out-File log1.txt
       $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    2 {
        # Fill in anything needed on second reboot; remove if unneeded
          Get-Process | Out-File log2.txt  
          $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    3 {
        # Fill in anything needed on third reboot; remove if unneeded
        # Create more reboots as needed
        $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Get-Process | Out-File log3.txt
       Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############      --END--      ################
    }

    default {
        # Dropper is complete; clean up
        rm $countfile
        rm $bootbatch
        rm $dropperscript
    }
}
'@

# Drop and run Dropper

$dropper | Out-File $dropperscript -Encoding 'OEM'

Invoke-Expression $dropperscript
```

But After Restart the Batch File runs in normal mode(and not in administrator mode) and Throws Access denied Error as follows

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIczh.png)

Please Help me run the batch in administrator after restart.

dropper.bat

```
powershell -c d:\temp\dropper.ps1 pause
```

And Dropper.ps1 that Is created in temp is as follows

```
#############################################
###        Configuration Variables        ###
                                            #
# Put any variables you'll use here
                                            # 
###                                       ###
#############################################

# Static Variables
$countfile = 'd:\temp\bootcount.txt'
$bootbatch = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\dropper.bat'
$dropperscript = 'd:\temp\dropper.ps1'

#################
##### Setup #####

# Bootstrap Batch
if (!(Get-Item $bootbatch -ea ignore)) {
    "powershell -c $dropperscript`npause" | Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM'
}

# Boot Count
if (Get-Item $countfile -ea ignore) {
    [int]$bootcount = Get-Content $countfile
    if ($bootcount -match "^\d{1,2}$") { ([int]$bootcount) ++ }
    else { $bootcount = 1 }
}
else { $bootcount = 1 }
$bootcount | Out-File $countfile


switch ($bootcount) {

    1 {

       Get-Process | Out-File log1.txt
       $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    2 {
        # Fill in anything needed on second reboot; remove if unneeded
          Get-Process | Out-File log2.txt  
          $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############     --REBOOT--     ###############
    }

    3 {
        # Fill in anything needed on third reboot; remove if unneeded
        # Create more reboots as needed
        $x=Read-Host "Press Enter"
        Get-Process | Out-File log3.txt
       Restart-Computer -Force
        ##################################################
        ###############      --END--      ################
    }

    default {
        # Dropper is complete; clean up
        rm $countfile
        rm $bootbatch
        rm $dropperscript
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to elevate the powershell script to "Run as Administrator"

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

You would however need to disable the prompt to confirm the request to run as admin. You can find that portion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/464758/how-do-i-disable-administrator-prompt-in-windows-8)

You can just copy and paste the below at the begin of your script.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}
```

To then run the batch file as Admin as well you need to call it like this

```
start-Process $bootbatch -Verb runas
```

or even without variable as

```
start-Process "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\dropper.bat" -Verb runas
```

Comment: Where exactly this change is to be made,I am basically new to this powershell world,So please help me!.> ' "powershell -c $dropperscript`npause" | Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM' '
 is is to be replaced with ' Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs (followed by what)

Comment: It Throws a admin prompt and then starts as a admin instance of powershell.But the batch file that runs at start up is not having elevated permissions

Comment: hence why I said you need to disable admin prompt.

Comment: its okay if it throws prompt, Problem is when it is restarting and running a batch. Its running it in normal mode, Even it requires Elevated permission

Comment: ok holdon, so you want to run the batch file as administrator and not the powershell script?

Comment: Both are to be run as an administrators,(I imagined that if PowerShell runs as admin even batch would, But I was wrong)

Comment: ok, so to confirm, does the ps1 file atleast now run as admin with the answer I posted?

Comment: Yes for now the powershell is opening up as admin

Comment: How do we make those changes? ? I don't understand As $bootbatch is just pointing to file and when to use Start-Powershell is a a confusion

Comment: If any changes are to be made its supposed to be something here ?? Is it not ?>>>if (!(Get-Item $bootbatch -ea ignore)) {
    "powershell -c $dropperscript`npause" | Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM'
}

Comment: ok, hold on. I see that this script is actually creating the batch file and dropper powershell script, putting it into startup. We would instead need to create the batch file to use `runas` once it is being run. can you edit question and add the content of a complete created dropper.bat file?

Comment: and dropper.ps1 if you can please

Comment: I am sorry  I didn't get it,You want me to change the title of the question?

Comment: no. I need to see how the batch file is generated, I cannot duplicate this unfortunately, so just add the content of both the batch file and dropper.ps1 file to the question.

Comment: Added the contents of dropper.bat and dropper.ps1

Comment: I got the solution to open powershell via batch file as an admin ,Changed "powershell -c $dropperscript`npause" | Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM' to $x='PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '''
$y=' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\temp\dropper.ps1""'' -Verb RunAs}"'

$x+$y| Out-File $bootbatch -Encoding 'OEM'

Comment: I see that the batch file just calls the powershell script, it is easy enough to call it from there as well,  but cool if you are sorted.